# Use count in AVG

Tags: sql, select, count, average

I have two selects with count that I need to use in a AVG. 
In theory an AVERAGE= A+B/C.
I have the value of A+B and C.
I'm doing a homework where I have a table prescriptions and a table for appointments. I need to know the AVG for prescriptions/appointments in the year 2017.
For example, in 2017 I had 6 appointments and 4 prescriptions. So the AVG=4/6.

```
This gives me A+B= 4.

select COUNT(*) FROM prescription
WHERE date_hour like '2017%';



This gives me C= 6.

select COUNT(*) FROM appointment
WHERE date_hour like '2017%';
```

I have done some research and no luck. I'm new to MYSQL. How can I calculate the AVG for these 2 selects?

Thank you

Comment: Although I didn't understand your logic about getting the average: select (select count(...) from prescription ...)/(select count(...) from appointment ...). BTW what does data_hour have to do with year when it looks like a string.

Comment: Sorry, it's DATE_HOUR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the division directly in a SELECT statement:

```
select
  (select COUNT(*) FROM prescription WHERE date_hour like '2017%') /
  (select COUNT(*) FROM appointment WHERE date_hour like '2017%') as averageresult
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just doing it for that one row in the SELECT statement, you could do the following:

```
 SELECT NUM/DEN FROM (
 SELECT COUNT(*) NUM FROM PRESCRIPTION
 WHERE DATA_HOUR LIKE '2017%')
 ,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) DEN FROM APPOINTMENT
 WHERE DATA_HOUR LIKE '2017%')
```

If you'd need to group this by multiple DATA_HOURS, more info regarding the aggregation method would be needed.